# Removing duplicated lines from a txt file

Tags: python, linux, awk

I am processing large text files (~20MB) containing data delimited by line.
Most data entries are duplicated and I want to remove these duplications to only keep one copy.

Also, to make the problem slightly more complicated, some entries are repeated with an extra bit of info appended. In this case I need to keep the entry containing the extra info and delete the older versions.

e.g.
I need to go from this:

```
BOB 123 1DB
JIM 456 3DB AX
DAVE 789 1DB
BOB 123 1DB
JIM 456 3DB AX
DAVE 789 1DB
BOB 123 1DB EXTRA BITS
```

to this:

```
JIM 456 3DB AX
DAVE 789 1DB
BOB 123 1DB EXTRA BITS
```

NB. the final order doesn't matter.

What is an efficient way to do this?

I can use awk, python or any standard linux command line tool.

Thanks.

Comment: A quick and dirty version would be `cat file|sort|uniq`, but that wouldn't handle the lines with the "extra bits"

Comment: Is it always one word and one number (and perhaps some added text)?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: sadly no, the number of columns changes from entry to entry (but is usually several) and the extra bits can be one or several columns. I'll modify my example to make this clearer...

Comment: Eliminating duplicate lines is easy.  "sort -u" will do that all by itself.  But you have to better define the partial match/substring better.  Is it always the first two fields that will match, then there will be more fields than that in the output?

Comment: Can there multiple value of EXTRA BITS for the same key?

Comment: @dj_segfault:  good point. Yes, the first two columns will always match.

Comment: @Spaceghost: I think that there will only be one value of 'EXTRA BITS' per key.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about the following (in Python):

```
prev = None
for line in sorted(open('file')):
  line = line.strip()
  if prev is not None and not line.startswith(prev):
    print prev
  prev = line
if prev is not None:
  print prev
```

If you find memory usage an issue, you can do the sort as a pre-processing step using Unix `sort` (which is [disk-based](http://vkundeti.blogspot.com/2008/03/tech-algorithmic-details-of-unix-sort.html)) and change the script so that it doesn't read the entire file into memory.

Comment: I slightly changed your code – I used `str.startswith` instead of slicing with `len`.

Comment: Great -I'm just testing this out now and from what I can tell it is working... I'll keep testing all the Answers and select the best solution soon. Thanks!

Comment: @Pete W: Out of curiosity, did you do any benchmarking with the different solutions? It'd be interesting to know how costly the `sorted` is for 20MB of data.

Comment: @shang: it didn't seem to cause any problems. This solution returned a result within a fraction of a second, which is more than adequate in this case. I haven't done formal benchmarks, but they all seemed to return results within a second or so.

Answer (score 3):

`awk '{x[$1 " " $2 " " $3] = $0} END {for (y in x) print x[y]}'`

If you need to specify the number of columns for different files:

```
awk -v ncols=3 '
  {
    key = "";
    for (i=1; i<=ncols; i++) {key = key FS $i}
    if (length($0) > length(x[key])) {x[key] = $0}
  }
  END {for (y in x) print y "\t" x[y]}
'
```

Comment: The downside to this is that `EXTRA BITS` won't be preserved unless it's a part the last row to match the first 3 columns in the file.

Comment: This is great -very neat! I'm testing it now to see if it works exactly as I need, but the first results are looking very good. I'll get back soon with a more definitive answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, as Joe Kington mentioned this doesn't quite work when the EXTRA BITS are not the most recent entry (which I've just found out does occur in my txt files in some instances) so it doesn't quite solve my problem.

Comment: @Pete, if you're interested, I added a test so that the line with the longest extra bits will be kept.

Comment: I believe you were missing a parenthesis there. Hope it's alright that I went ahead and added it in. (Though I think (?) the OP might have wanted just `for (y in x) print x[y]`? That's beside the point, though...)  As much as I like python, it's a shame that awk is so often forgotten these days! :)

Answer (score 2):

This or a slight variant should do:

```
finalData = {}
for line in input:
    parts = line.split()
    key,extra = tuple(parts[0:3]),parts[3:]
    if key not in finalData or extra:
        finalData[key] = extra

pprint(finalData)
```

outputs:

```
{('BOB', '123', '1DB'): ['EXTRA', 'BITS'],
 ('DAVE', '789', '1DB'): [],
 ('JIM', '456', '3DB'): ['AX']}
```

Comment: The variant should probably either sort the input first (so as not to lose extra bits if an item with extra bits occurs before a duplicate without), or use [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), to gather any extra bits occurences, for example `finalData = collections.defaultdict(set)` and then `finalData[key].add(extra)` (you still have to decide what to do with different "EXTRA BITS" for one key)

Comment: That was a deliberate decision as it wasn't clear if we should remove the `EXTRA BITS` in that case... easy enough to add.

Answer (score 2):

This variation on glenn jackman's answer should work regardless of the position of lines with extra bits:

```
awk '{idx = $1 " " $2 " " $3; if (length($0) > length(x[idx])) x[idx] = $0} END {for (idx in x) print x[idx]}' inputfile
```

Or

```
awk -v ncols=3 '
  {
    key = "";
    for (i=1; i<=ncols; i++) {key = key FS $i}
    if (length($0) > length(x[key])) x[key] = $0
  }
  END {for (y in x) print x[y]}
' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to define a function to split your line into important bits and extra bits, then you can do:

```
def split_extra(s):
    """Return a pair, the important bits and the extra bits."""
    return blah blah blah

data = {}
for line in open('file'):
    impt, extra = split_extra(line)
    existing = data.setdefault(impt, extra)
    if len(extra) > len(existing):
        data[impt] = extra

out = open('newfile', 'w')
for impt, extra in data.iteritems():
    out.write(impt + extra)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you need the extra bits the fastest way is to create a set of unique entries (sort -u will do) and then you must compare each entry against each other, e.g.

```
if x.startswith(y) and not y.startswith(x)
```

and just leave x and discard y.

Answer (score 1):

If you have perl and want only the last entry to be preserved :

```
cat file.txt | perl -ne 'BEGIN{%k={}} @_ = split(/ /);$kw = shift(@_); $kws{$kw} = "@_"; END{ foreach(sort keys %kws){ print "$_ $kws{$_}";} }' > file.new.txt
```

Comment: UUOC.  Pass file.txt as the first argument to perl

Comment: Shouldn't really matter I guess

Answer (score 1):

The function `find_unique_lines` will work for a file object or a list of strings.

```
import itertools

def split_line(s):
    parts = s.strip().split(' ')
    return " ".join(parts[:3]), parts[3:], s

def find_unique_lines(f):
    result = {}
    for key, data, line in itertools.imap(split_line, f):
        if data or key not in result:
            result[key] = line
    return result.itervalues()

test = """BOB 123 1DB
JIM 456 3DB AX
DAVE 789 1DB
BOB 123 1DB
JIM 456 3DB AX
DAVE 789 1DB
BOB 123 1DB EXTRA BITS""".split('\n')

for line in find_unique_lines(test):
        print line
```

```
BOB 123 1DB EXTRA BITS
JIM 456 3DB AX
DAVE 789 1DB
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I don't think this works for the case where the EXTRA BITS are not the last entry (which can occur, although I admit this wasn't obvious from my question).

Comment: @Pete W: It does. The condition `if data or key not in result` stores a line if 1) it contains data OR 2) if the prefix doesn't yet exist in the dictionary. It's been tested with data that has EXTRA BITS in the middle too.

Comment: I apologize, your example as you've written it using a string does work. I had been testing it using a file (i.e. replacing test with file = open('data.txt') )and it is just returning the most recent line (without the extra bits). I'm trying to reproduce this with the sample data I provided in a file, but with the sample data I get it returning 2 lines for Bob -both with and without the extra bits... I'm confused!

Comment: @Pete W: Could there be extra white spaces somewhere? I added an extra `split()` call which should take care of that. It's not important since you already got a working solution from another poster, but I'm just interested in knowing where the bug is so that I can learn from my mistakes. :)

Comment: I think it must be an issue with white space. Your latest solution worked for me with the sample data in a file. For some reason, when I use it on the real data it still returns the data without the 'EXTRA BITS' if they weren't the most recent. I guess there must be some subtle differences between the sample data I provided and the real data I'm using, but that's my problem not yours! Your solution correctly answers the question!