# Compressing a large text file

Tags: python

I want to remove duplicate strings in python and just keep one string. I referred to this example 
[Removing duplicated lines from a txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948509/removing-duplicated-lines-from-a-txt-file)

eg: input
BOB 123 1DB
JIM 456 3DB AX
DAVE 789 1DB
BOB 123 1DB
JIM 456 3DB AX
DAVE 789 1DB
BOB 123 1DB EXTRA BITS

output:
JIM 456 3DB AX
DAVE 789 1DB
BOB 123 1DB EXTRA BITS

but i should implement similar code in python without using inbuilt functions like sorted(), line.strip() and line.startswith(). It should use basic functions like read, write ans so on. Also the output should display the line numbers as well in addition to the string with increasing order.

Comment: Then try to implement it first.

Comment: I'm aware you're asking about python. But if you just want to do it and you happen to be under Linux, the command line: `sort filename | uniq` will do the job for you.

Comment: @gongzhitaao: that won't handle the EXTRA BITS stuff.

Comment: @DSM Oops, miss that. Sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

I would probably implement it like this:

1. Create a dictionary to hold strings that have been found. Initialize that dictionary to be empty.
2. Iterate over each line of the file. Check if the line is in the dictionary.
3. If the line is in the dictionary, do nothing.
4. If the line is not in the dictionary, output it, and add it to the dictionary.

It's not clear what you mean by "increasing order". Your sample output doesn't appear to be in increasing order in any way that I can discern.